# Error "Please Restart From The Topmost Level" with Areca ARC-1883i

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using python 3 with python-requests in order to upload a volume key to unlock the Areca controller, but I keep getting "Please Restart From The Topmost Level". For anyone not familiar with these controllers, they support hardware level encryption and they have an http server running on them which you can connect from the out-of-band ethernet port.

Normally you just enter the address, login, go to 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/volkey.htm', choose the key file, confirm and upload. Using the chrome dev tools I found that the url used is the 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/UPLFIRM'. Following what I saw, I wrote the following code according to http://docs.python-requests.org:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

# Define Useful Variables

url_volkey = 'http://192.168.2.8/volkey.htm'
url_UPLFIRM = 'http://192.168.2.8/UPLFIRM'
url = 'http://192.168.2.8/index.htm'
username = 'admin'
password = '0000'
realm = 'Raid Console'

areca_key = open ('/home/manolis/Desktop/areca-key', 'rb')

multipart_data = MultipartEncoder (
    fields = {
        'FIRM': ('areca-key', areca_key, 'application/octet-stream'),
        'CFM': '1',
        'B1': 'Submit',
    }
)

# Begin Making connection

session = requests.Session ()
response = session.get (url)
cookies = dict (response.cookies)
print ("Status: %s" %(response.status_code))
print ("%s " %(response.headers))
print ("%s " %(response.request.headers))
print ("%s " %(response.content))

session.auth = auth=HTTPDigestAuth(username, password)
response = session.post (url, verify=False, cookies=cookies)
print ("Status: %s" %(response.status_code))
print ("%s " %(response.headers))
print ("%s " %(response.request.headers))
print ("%s " %(response.content))

session.headers.update ({'referer': 'http://192.168.2.8/volkey.htm'})
response = session.post (url_UPLFIRM, verify=False, cookies=cookies, data=multipart_data)
print ("Status: %s" %(response.status_code))
print ("%s " %(response.headers))
print ("%s " %(response.request.headers))
print ("%s " %(response.content))
```

I am using MultipartEncoder based on what I saw from the chrome dev tools.
[image: chrome dev tools]

I am really stuck here. It's obvious I am missing something but I can't understand what. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with web technologies. Any help/suggestion will be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost sure that you should not `post` on `index.htm`. Go there hit right mouse button on the link/button - and then `Inspect`, there is shortcut `CTRL-SHIFT-I` for that. There check link/button or form, where exactly submit action goes. For more information about form, go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp). I know it is a bit silly, but it is better to know then to expect. So check your form's attributes, other tags to see where to `post`.

Other option is to have dev-tools open on network tab. Go over your process, and all the requests will be there.

I'm guessing a bit, so if you have more questions, just post comment(s), and I'll try to comment/edit this post.

Comment: This was actually it. My mistake was that I was using post instead of get on the index.htm. Thank you very much!! Now it accepts the key and prints "Status:Encryption Key Validated" and unlocks the volume.